# C# webAPI restrict route

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

in a webapi project's WebAPIConfig.cs, 2 routes are added

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ActionApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I try to create an apiController contains below functions

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "get";
}
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("ByWait")]
public string[] ByWait(int id)
{
    return "bywait";
}
```

I expects that 
requesting /api/controllername/1234 returns "get", and 
requesting /api/controllername/bywait/1234 returns "bywait".

However, the actual result is 
/api/controllername/1234 >> throw exception Multiple actions were found that match the request
/api/controllername/bywait/1234 >> "by wait"

However can fix the issue?
s.t how to restrict the function ByWait only accepts request containing action so that it only response to /api/controllername/bywait/1234 and ignore /api/controllername/1234

Or there is other better solution?

Thanks

Comment: The "DefaultApi" route configuration should be at the last. So that the specific route evaluation happens before falling to the Default route mapping.  try putting `DefaultApi` after `ActionApi` in route mapping code.

Comment: if i change the order of Maphttproute. i cant even call the /api/controllername/1234 successfully, it throw exception shows 1234 isn't a valid action name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can change WebApiConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get()
{
    return "get-default";
}

[HttpGet]
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "get" + id;
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("api/values/bywait/{id}")]
public string ByWait(int id)
{
    return "bywait";
}
```

Comment: Route should be "api/test/bywait/{id}" for bywait. get with id somehow unable to call by /api/test/5. but it can be requested by /api/test?id=5. nvm , it can solve the issue.